# Implementing IComparable<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I am getting the following error message when trying to tweak Listing 3.4 from Jon Skeet's book, C# in depth...

> The type 'list_3_4.Dog' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method     'list_3_4.Program.CompareToDefault(T)'. 
>       There is no implicit reference conversion from 'list_3_4.Dog' to 'System.IComparable'.

Here is my code...

```
using System;

namespace list_3_4
{
     class Program
     {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
               //string mystring;
               Dog d = new Dog("howie");

               Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault("x"));
               Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(10));
               Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(0));
               Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(-10));              
               Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(DateTime.MinValue));

               Console.WriteLine(CompareToDefault(d));

               Console.ReadKey();
          }

          static int CompareToDefault<T> (T value) where T: IComparable<T>
          {
               return value.CompareTo(default(T));               
          }

     }

     public class Dog 
     {
          private string _name;

          public Dog(string name)
          {
               _name = name;
          }
         }
}
```

How do I add a reference type like a "Dog" to work with Jon Skeets code listing??? I understand that Dog needs to implement IComparable but I don't know how!

Comment: Your `Dog` class doesn't appear to implement `IComparable<Dog>`, as specified by the generic constraint `where T : IComparable<T>`.

Comment: +1 For a code sample that I could copy, paste and play with. Although a question would have been nice lol

Comment: the following wont work   public class Dog : IComparable<T>, I tried public class Dog: IComarable<Dog>...that works!

Comment: @DemetriusBerlioz This is nonsensical for reference types, as they will always default to `null` using `default(T)`, so you may as well just test for null: `if (d == null)`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth thanks for unscrewing me on this one!

Answer (score 13):

You define the methods by saying you need a type `T` that is an `IComparable<T>` :

```
where T: IComparable<T>
```

But `Dog` does not implement `IComparable<Dog>`

You need to do:

```
public class Dog : IComparable<Dog>
{
 //this will allow you to do a quick name comparison
 public string Name { get; set;}
 public int CompareTo(Dog other)
 {//compare dogs by name
        return this._name.CompareTo(other.Name);
 }
}
```

**Note**: `default(T)` will return **null** for reference types, so you should do a null check somewhere. Read about [default on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Demetrius The final implementation that you decide upon should do null checking on `_name` and `other` and `other.Name`.

Comment: You don't actually need the `Name` property.  If you do add it you should at least make the setter private too.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth or you could just use the static `string.Compare` which does the null checking for you.

Comment: Yes, I attempted an implementation as you point out, but didn't realize what the "CompareTo" was attached to...just the object itself...as in this.CompareTo(other)...that won't work. As Alex points out above, it's off the property..._name.CompareTo(other._name)...what if there where no property???

Comment: @Servy Fair enough. I cannot remember the implementation specifics, so I'm not entirely sure if `other` also needs a null check. For clarity I always tend to, but I've never actually tested that lol

Comment: To all, I have tried to up vote as many of you that gave sincere answers and comments, although,  I have a feeling I am going to answer my own question as soon as I finish reading Chapter 4 of Skeet's book..."Saying nothing with nullable types"

Answer (score 10):

Your `Dog` class should implement [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 public class Dog: IComparable<Dog>
 {
      private string _name;

      public Dog(string name)
      {
           _name = name;
      }

      public int CompareTo( Dog other )
      {
           if (other == null)
               return 1;
           return string.Compare( _name, other._name );
      }
 }
```

Comment: public class Dog: IComparable<T> is not working, only public class Dog: IComparable<Dog> is working...sort of...now I am getting a NullReferenceException ???

Comment: @DemetriusBerlioz I have added a check for `other == null`, it should work now.